# Null Object Reference when trying to call a method from a list of objects extracted from sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am having trouble diagnosing an error after I extract some data from an sqlite database and pass it to another class. I think the passing is where I have the problem.

Fact: My database is filled with data, of the following format:

```
1447206226445|1
1447206228288|0
1447206462437|1
```

(First column is a long, second column is an integer)

In my main class, I am trying to search the database for a range of long values, and the display things accordingly.  I use:

```
Days[] daysList = dbHandler.findRange(first.getTimeInMillis(), last.getTimeInMillis());
```

to get a list of dates that I want, where *first* and *last* are Calendar objects.

I then use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < daysList.length; j++) {
        if (daysList[j].getID() > first.getTimeInMillis() && daysList[j].getID() < second.getTimeInMillis()) {
        ...
    ...
...
```

to sort through the data in daysList. However, I get the following error here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long com.example.william.timeclockr.Days.getID()' on a null object reference
```

Here is my DBHandler findRange() method:

```
public Days[] findRange(long startRange, long endRange) {
    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_DAYS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_DAYSLONG + " >= " + startRange + " AND " + COLUMN_DAYSLONG + " <= " + endRange + ";";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    Days day = new Days();
    Days[] days = new Days[cursor.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    do {
    //while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    day.setID(cursor.getLong(0));
    day.setStatus(cursor.getInt(1));
    days[i] = day;
    i++;
    cursor.moveToNext();
    //}
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return days;
}
```

And here is my Days class:

```
package com.example.william.timeclockr;

public class Days {

    private long _id;
    private int _status;

    public Days() {

    }

    public Days(long id, int status) {
        this._id = id;
        this._status = status;
    }

    public Days(int status) {
        this._status = status;
    }

    public void setID(long id) {
        this._id = id;
    }

    public long getID() {
        return this._id;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this._status = status;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return this._status;
    }
}
```

I know this is a lot of information, but I feel like I am making a really rookie mistake passing that list around, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be all in your `do-while` loop in the `findRange()` method. You need to instantiate a new `Days` object each time through the loop. Also, you're calling `cursor.moveToNext();` twice each time through, which is advancing the `Cursor` more quickly than the array index, causing the eventual `NullPointerException`.

```
do {
    day = new Days();
    day.setID(cursor.getLong(0));
    day.setStatus(cursor.getInt(1));
    days[i] = day;
    i++;
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: Ohhh ok wow that was pretty dumb. Nice, I definitely missed the extra cursor.moveToNext() when I was changing that loop up too. I am now getting a completely different error which....makes me somewhat happy...

Comment: What's the new error? Btw, you can sort the results from the query easily in the SQL, or with Collections and Comparators in Java. Might be easier than the double `for`-loops.

Comment: It was just a cursor error, I didn't have protection from errors around my cursor, but I got that fixed easily. Yeah I actually don't need to sort the data since it is actually stored chronologically, but the `for` loops are to sort through the data and allocate each day according to what day of the week it is. It is a bit bulky, will probably slim it down in the future.